# How to disable wordpress redirect

Tags: wordpress

At the moment I am trying to transition my wordpress site to another host. I got a backup and imported it to a new database. I am trying to test all functionalities on a new database plus hosting provider.

When connecting to it, it redirects me to my live site.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256457/disable-ssl-https-for-wordpress

I followed steps here. My current testing url lets say is  test-001-site3.btempurl.com

I changed the values from the query below to my testing url

`SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home';`

no success, I've also edited the config file to have

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'test-001-site3.btempurl.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'test-001-site3.btempurl.com' );

may i ask how do I disable the redirect, I am unable to access /wp-admin as well

Answer (score 2):

Normally defining in the config.php should work.

Have you tried entering the new url with http:// or https:// prefix?

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Check out this mysql generation script, it helped me a lot http://hitautodestruct.github.io/wordpress-db-migrate/

Comment: hmmm, that´s wild, have you checked the .htaccess file in the root directory for any redirects?